# LINQ multi-table query: error on INCLUDE

Tags: asp.net, linq, include

**Query:**  Given a cuisineID (type of cuisine), return the list of restaurants that offer that cuisine and also return the city for each og those restauarants (1 per restaurant).  The RESTAURANT and CITY tables have a foreign-key relationship based on CITY_ID.  I have added a Linq to SQL .dbml file (FVRG.dbml) and loaded all the tables for my database in the FVRGdatacontext file.  When I look at the file, I can see the foreign key relationships between each of the tables.  However, Intellisense does not recognize usage of the include statement and returns the following error.  Can you please help?  Regards, Susan

> Error 1:  'System.Data.Linq.Table' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a
>   first argument of type  'System.Data.Linq.Table' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   H:\ASP.Net\FVRG\DL\DLgetRestaurants.cs  20  68  DL

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DL
{
    public class DLgetRestaurants
    {
        DL.FVRGDataContext db = new FVRGDataContext();

        public IEnumerable <RESTAURANT> getRestaurants(string cuisineName)
        {

        var cuisineID = db.CUISINEs.First(s => s.CUISINE_NAME == cuisineName).CUISINE_ID;


            var restaurantList = from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs.Include("CITies")
                                 where RESTAURANT.CITY.Any(t => t.CITY_ID == 2)
                                 select RESTAURANT;

            return restaurantList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Accept some of your other question's answers before asking new questions.

Comment: I made a mistake in typing the question but I can't figure out how to pull it back>  Do you know how?

Comment: Also, I have replied to each of the questions I posed.  Sorry for any discourtesy.

Comment: dude I didn't even know you can use `Include` in that way...

Comment: @johnny you can't in LINQ To SQL. `Include()` is an Entity Framework extension method.

Comment: @p.campbell thank you Mr.Campbell, I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var db = new YourDataContext();

List<Restaurant> result = (from c in db.Cities
                           join r in db.Restaurants on c.CityID equals r.CityID
                           where c.CuisineName == cuisineName && c.CityID == cityID
                           select r).ToList(); 

return result;
```

That is, of course, as long as you have a database table called `Cities` and a table called `Restaurants` with a `CityID` foreign key to the primary key of the `Cities` table.... Does that make sense?

**EDIT**

If you wanted multiple joins you could have something like this...

```
List<Restaurant> result = (from c in db.Cities
                           join r in db.Restaurants on c.CityID equals r.CityID
                           join x in db.SomethingElse on r.SomethingID equals x.SomethingID
                           where c.CuisineName == cuisineName && c.CityID == cityID
                           select r).ToList();
```

Comment: YES!  it works but when I look at the data that is being returned it is not including the CITY_NAME.  Do I have to specify that this is returned along with the restarant name in my select?  Sorry, I'm such a newbie to LINQ.  Thank you ~susan~

Comment: Also, one more thing, if I want to add a 2nd join to my CUISINE table, do I just use a '&&" at the end of the join line and add the "ON ..... EQUALS ?  pharse for the second join?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include more detail regarding LINQ joins, but I am afraid without knowing more about your database I am unable to help you as to why the `CITY_NAME` field is not included, sorry! I would suggest just playing around to see what you can get. Check out [101 samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746) for more.

Comment: Thank you!!!  You've been a great help and I was missing using a table reference in my ListView <%#Eval("CITY.CITY_NAME") %>.  I'm going to put up a separate question on the JOIN problem.  With your help I got further, but there's not enuf room in the Comment section to put all my code.  Again, thanks ~susan~

Comment: Ha, I should have known that the `CITY_NAME` field was a part of the `City` table! Pretty obvious really! Glad I could help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

LINQ To SQL doesn't support the `Include()` extension method, as in EF.

I suspect you're wanting `.LoadWith()` instead on the DataLoadOptions.

```
var db = new MyDataContext();
var dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Cities>(p => p.Restaurants);
db.LoadOptions = dlo;

var restaurantList = from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs
                     where RESTAURANT.CITY.Any(t => t.CITY_ID == cuisineID)
                     select RESTAURANT;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought that by dragging each of my tales into the O/R Designer I had created the 'entity classes?'